# How can I use grep to retrieve two patterns within the same fixed-length sections of text?

Tags: regex, grep, alternation

I'm trying to extract information from a file using grep and make connections between related occurrences. For example, my file may contain the following repeated pattern:

```
Section
Info1
etc etc
Info2
```

I want to be able to grep for Section and grab `Info1` and `Info2`. I tried using an OR pattern, i.e., `Info1\|Info2`, but this greps all `Info1` and `Info2` in random order. I want `Info1` and `Info2` of each section be retrieved together.

All sections are the same length. There's always a fixed number of lines between `Info1` and `Info2`. The desired output is:

```
Info1
Info2
Info1
Info2
...
```

where consecutive `Info1`/`Info2`s are from the same section
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are these just lines containing `Info1` and `Info2`, or is there more content? Is `etc etc` always just one line? Is `Section` always exactly `Section`? According to your question, you want to *always* find `Section Info1 Info2` - do you really want that? What does your real data look like? The desired output? What have you tried?

Comment: Added mote details to the question

Comment: How does `grep 'Info1\|Info2'` not give you exactly the result you want? Are there some `Info1` or `Info2` lines you don't want?

Comment: No, as I said the problem is that 'Info1\|Info2' seems to randomly pick Info1 and Info2 and the output is in such way that two consecutive Info1 and Info2 are not necessarily from the same section

Comment: Grep doesn't change the order of input lines. Can you show your exact input (or a minimal version of it that reproduces the problem), your exact command and your exact output?

Comment: You're right, I was running this as two parts grep, e.g. grep -A 17 '...' | grep '...' but 17 wasn't accurate and as a result I was getting inaccurate results. I counted correctly and it's now working fine

Comment: In general, AWK or Perl in paragraph mode are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

### Line-Anchored Grep

You don't need alternation or pipes for the example you posted. Given your corpus, the following works just fine:

```
$ grep '^Info' /tmp/foo
Info1
Info2
Info1
Info2
```

Unless you have lines *between* sections that start with `Info` then you don't need anything more complicated. However, assuming that your real corpus is more complicated, and that you might need to do additional processing within each section, I address fixed-length sections below.

### Filtering Fixed-Length Sections with Grep

Assuming each section is exactly 4 lines, like:

```
Section
Info1
etc etc
Info2

Section
Info1
etc etc
Info2
```

then you can use the `-A` flag to define the amount of context *after* the match to return. You can then pipe that into an anchored expression that matches `Info` at the beginning of any line. This returns the results you wanted:

```
$ grep -F -A3 Section /tmp/foo | grep '^Info'
Info1
Info2
Info1
Info2
```